# Occasional 401 (Unauthorized) error when trying to simply iframe embed Google Calendar

Tags: google-calendar-api

I see a lot of issues about using the Calendar API and getting a 401 error. I've got an even simpler situation. We have an embedded calendar here:
http://evergreenchorale.org/content/center-stage-calendar

It uses all the latest credential techniques Google suggests, and the calendar is set to shared-public.

For me, it's working in all browsers, all the time, incognito/InPrivate or not. For most users, it's working.

For some users however, it fails to load, reporting a 401 (Unauthorized) error and not loading ANY of the calendar contents (the iframe calendar itself loads and renders, but with no events). The result looks like this:
http://i.imgur.com/FWmlb2F.jpg

You can see the 401 error on the side there.

I can't see anything I'm doing wrong here.

I'm mostly a web hack, I'm a C++ coder by day, and just do web stuff to help out others, so if I'm committing a JavaStupid mistake, go easy on me. But I was trying to follow all the guides I could find.

The embed code is this:

which contains the Google Calendar URL:
https://www.google.com/calendar/embed?src=evergreenchorale.org_bgfs4eu3bfd01lvqa28flvgpuk%40group.calendar.google.com&color=%23A32929&ctz=America/Denver

The expected behavior is... that it will load and display a calendar with the events shown.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: Facing the same problem. Did you fix this?